# How to unrar/unzip with Objective-C, including single file retrieval

Tags: objective-c, zip, rar

I have a need to handle various rar/zip files, in Objective-C. Ideally I'd like to be as flexible as possible in terms of rar/zip versions. I'd also like to be able to only extract certain files from the rar/zip files, after pulling out a list of the file contents.

If that wasn't enough, I'd like to be able to access and modify the zip comment.

Is this easily possible in objective-c? I've searched around a lot and found a lot of half-finished libraries that don't do everything I want, or only support rar up to version 2, or don't support extracting single files.

I know I could just use the command line unzip tool that ships with MacOS Panther and up, but this seems inelegant and doesn't help me with rar files, as no unrar application ships with MacOS by default.

Can anyone point me at a decent library that does one or the other of these two types of files, or a recommended best approach for dealing with this problem? I know that one option is to wrap the unrar source, and also wrap the zlib source, but this to me is a daunting task. If there's no other option I'll do it - any advice or guidance on this would be gratefully received.

Thanks!

Answer (score -4):

Yes, doing that it's easy in objective C. For zip files just use [ZLIB](http://zlib.net/) (it's already included in **Mac OS X**.

RAR is not that simple though. Look for a **C library** (not an Objective-C library). There will be way more **C libraries** for **RAR** handling than **Objective-C** ones. And you can use all **C libraries** you want within an **Objective-C** program.

Comment: zlib alone does not support zip files.  See the [FAQ](http://www.zlib.net/zlib_faq.html#faq11).